# Как заполнить двумерный массив одним циклом?

Tags: java

Подскажите, как заполнить двумерный массив одним циклом в Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас имеется двумерный массив размером M * N, то можно организовать цикл следующим образом

```
for ( int i = 0; i < M * N; i++ ) a[i / N][i % N] = ( i / N ) * ( i % N );
```

Или

```
for ( int i = 0; i < M * N; i++ ) a[i / N][i % N] = ( i / N + 1 ) * ( i % N + 1);
```

Comment: мне нужно заполнить двумерный массив таблицей умножения, как я понял, нужно сделать составное условие

Comment: @kuheguluy Не совсем понятно, какими значениями вам нужно заполнить элементы массива.

Comment: есть массив a[n][m], нужно заполнить a[i][j]=i*j, одним циклом

Comment: @kuheguluy Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, какой раз уже выручаешь;

Comment: @kuheguluy Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)